# Package emacs-snapshot-nox has unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies, emacs

I'm trying to install emacs24 for an external repository, but I receive an error regarding unmet dependencies and wonder how I can continue the installation and resolve this error?

The output looks like this:

```
dito@dito:~$ sudo apt-get install emacs-snapshot-nox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  emacs-snapshot-nox: Depends: emacs-snapshot-bin-common (= 1:20111012-1+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libncurses5 (>= 5.7+20100313) but 5.7+20090803-2ubuntu3 is to be installed
                      PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6) but 1.15.5.6ubuntu4.5 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
dito@dito:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get an updated package for dpkg from this ppa.
https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/programs-ppa2